# VBA pie chart with dynamic data

Tags: vba, pie-chart

I am trying to insert data in my pie chart but something goes wrong.

Apparently, VBA does not like this:

```
  ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(r, 2), ws2.Cells(r + inc, 2))

  ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(r, 15), ws2.Cells(r + inc, 15))
```

So I have tried this:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Dashboard!$B$"&r&":$B$"&r+inc
```

But it is still not working....

Comment: Does somebody knows a better solution?

Comment: The .Name of a series just requires a single value. Use just the .Values part or use .SetSourceData of ActiveChart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a range declared inside your code and the SetSourceData method:

```
Set my_range = work.Range("E1:F" & i - 1)
dash.ChartObjects("My Chart").Chart.SetSourceData Source:=my_range
```

That is what works for me.

Comment: Also this is working:

    set rangeA = ws.range("A1:A10")

    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = rangeA